# How do I add an xml file to my project?

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to start out with LinqtoXml.
I have added (I think) the right namespaces

```
XElement contactsFromFile = XElement.Load("App_Data/test.xml");
```

Doesn't work... I get a
"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\App_Data\test.xml'"
error...

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
XElement contactsFromFile =
        XElement.Load( Server.MapPath( "~/App_Data/test.xml" ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a system property called "HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath" which gives you the root directory where your app is deployed.  I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "/App_Data/text.xml"
```